# How to get value from firebase in react?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get value from firebase and input in some page with the first four character.

Here is my code.

```
'use strict'
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player';
import Array from '../Array';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';


export default () => {

 const getData =(info) => firebase.database.ref('answers').once('value',gotData(
    info,(snapshot)=>{info.push(snapshot.val())}
  ));





  function gotData(data){
    var scores=data.val();
    var keys = Object.keys(scores);
    console.log(keys)
  } 

    return (
      <div>
          <div className="video">
          <ReactPlayer  url={Array[0].url} playing/>
          <div>
              <p>Your guess: </p>
             <p>{getData}</p>
               <p>Right Answer:</p>
               <p>{Array[0].name}</p>
          </div> 

          </div>   

      </div>
    )
  }
```

Here is my data structure in firebase.

[image]

I want to insert, for example, answer2 value of the first four character "real" into the

```
              {/* <p> want to input the value answer here.</p>  */}
```